# What does 'xxx is a dog` mean?

Tags: meaning

I just saw an sentence from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22210816/342235):

> But the problem grows and the next thing you know your maven build is checking 50 repos for every artifact and build time is a dog

What does `xxx is a dog` mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Dog* can have several slang meanings.

In this case, it refers to another piece of slang, that is deemed to be quite offensive.

If something is really hard, really difficult or a pain in the backside, one may, very informally, express this as:

> xxx is a (son of a) bitch.

(This can also be said about people, meaning that they are in one or several ways, not pleasant.)

This expression is, like I said, deemed very offensive in many situations (most, really).

If we take it literally, however, *a bitch* is a female dog, and her *son* would (bar Greek mythology) be a *dog*. Even if we refer directly to the *bitch* instead of her son, she's a *dog*.

So instead of the offensive *(son of) a bitch*, the author uses the euphemistic *dog*.

Comment: Really? I'd love to see some references on that. Examples? Earliest date used (in that sense)?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Of what? _xxx is a bitch_? Google will provide you plenty of examples. For the rest, I just based my answer on the fact that a bitch is a dog, for which I'm sure you can easily find enough references.

Comment: I'm just saying I take your answer as folk etymology, absent any substantiated connection.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock If you do not see a connection between _bitch_ and _dog_, you can take it as you want :)

Comment: As for _xxx is a bitch_, see [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&biw=1680&bih=949&q=%22work%20is%20a%20bitch%22&oq=%22work%20is%20a%20bitch%22&gs_l=hp.3...16373.16796.1.16988.4.4.0.0.0.0.69.238.4.4.0.elfrh...0...1.1.62.psy-ab..6.0.0.yrhuLbCU54k&pbx=1&bav=on.2%2Cor.&bvm=bv.86956481%2Cd.ZWU&ion=1&pws=1&rct=j). Do turn off safe search, because that will hide _bitch_. I get 347000 results.

Comment: If you call my girlfriend a dog, are you calling her a "son of a bitch?" No, you are just saying she's ugly. It's not a euphemism for anything. ngrams only show both expressions are popular; they don't show when, whether or how often one is used as a euphemism for the other.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: that is why I started with mentioning there are other slang meanings. Especially when applied to **people**. Do you want to imply that the author calls _build time_ **ugly**?

Comment: Although the euphemistic slang has been used for people according to [this meme](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3pqsm3) (hound dog -> bitch). Not very convincing, I agree.

Comment: not ugly. My alternate hypothesis is "dog-slow"  here's a reference from the same genre (software development)     http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1922871

Comment: I agree with both oerkelens and Brian Hitchcock. I also think this definition is apt: [dog](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dog_1) "3. *informal* something that is of bad quality or very unsuccessful. *I invested in an Internet start-up but it turned out to be a real dog.*"